# How to add id's and values to a article tag dynamically through jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to add a mix of ids and path to the article element dynamically through jquery

This is the HTML article tag

```
<article class=test> <article/>
```

I tried to do this in jquery.

```
var assetHtml='data-asset-share-id="asset" data-asset-share-asset="/dam/pic.jpg" id="/dam/pic.jpg"';

$( ".test" ).append(assetHtml);
```

But this adds the entire id and elements in a string format something like this in quotes making it a string whereas they are id's in the text area of article tag instead of inside article tag

```
<article class="test">"data-asset-share-id="asset" data-asset-share-asset="/dam/pic.jpg" id="/dam/pic.jpg""</article>
```

I expect the output to be in this format

```
<article class=test data-asset-share-id="asset" data-asset-share-asset="/dam/pic.jpg" id="/dam/pic.jpg" > </article>
```

How to achieve this?

Comment: $(selector).attr("attribute","value");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`append()` is used to add content *within* an element. To amend the attributes of the element to it you can use `attr()`:

```
$(".test").attr({
  'data-asset-share-id': 'asset',
  'data-asset-share-asset': '/dam/pic.jpg',
  'id': '/dam/pic.jpg'
});
```

Alternatively you can use a combination of `prop()` and `data()`. The latter of which puts the values in to jQuery's cache, not the DOM, which gives better performance, but requires that you also use `data()` as a getter to retrieve the values:

```
$(".test").prop('id', '/dam/pic.jpg').data({
  'asset-share-id': 'asset',
  'asset-share-asset': '/dam/pic.jpg'
});
```

Comment: Can I add multiple id's with the same id name ? something like this

Comment: No. There can be only one `id` attribute on an element, and the value has to be unique within the DOM.

Comment: Can I add this same article tag multiple times through jquery with different asset paths?<article class=test data-asset-share-id="asset" data-asset-share-asset="/dam/pic.jpg" id="/dam/pic.jpg" > </article>

Comment: Yes, but the `id` needs to change on every element.

Answer (score 1):

You can use following logic using `split()` and `attr()` methods

```js
$(function(){
var assetHtml='data-asset-share-id="asset" data-asset-share-asset="/dam/pic.jpg" id="/dam/pic.jpg"';
var assetAttr = assetHtml.split(' ');
for(var i=0; i<assetAttr.length; i++) {
   var attr = assetAttr[i].split('=');
   $( ".test" ).attr(attr[0], attr[1]);
}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<article class=test> Article<article/>
```

Comment: I think you've over complicated this by assuming the string in the original attempt could not be amended.

Answer (score 1):

I recognise that the question asks for a solution using the `jQuery` library but for the sake of completeness, here, additionally, is a solution using vanilla javascript.

**Working Example:**

```js
// GET THE ARTICLE ELEMENT
const testArticle = document.getElementsByClassName('test')[0];

// CREATE OBJECT CONTAINING ATTRIBUTES AND VALUES
const assetHtml = {

  'data-asset-share-id' : 'asset',
  'data-asset-share-asset' : '/dam/pic.jpg',
  'id' : '/dam/pic.jpg'
}

// GET THE ATTRIBUTES (ie. THE KEYS OF THE OBJECT ABOVE)
const assetHtmlAttributes = Object.keys(assetHtml);

// ASSIGN ATTRIBUTES AND VALUES TO THE ELEMENT
assetHtmlAttributes.forEach((attribute) => testArticle.setAttribute(attribute, assetHtml[attribute]));

// VIEW UPDATED ELEMENT
console.log(testArticle);
```

```html
<article class="test"></article>
```